# Matlab Function inside simulink

Tags: matlab, function, simulink, frequency

I need to use a Matlab function inside of a Simulink model. I know how to use a Matlab function to do simple stuff. But what I need now is a little bit more complicated. Let me give you a basic example.

Assume that I need to have a block to generate a sine wave to be viewed directly on the scope (I know that there is already a sine-wave block, I'm just taking that as an example). If I'm writing in Matlab NOT in Simulink, I would do something like:

```
 t = [0:1/30000:0.2];
 A = 1;
 f =10000;
 y = A*sin(2*pi*f*t);
 plot(t(1:100),y(1:100))
```

***How can I build the same function inside a Simulink matlab-function block and see the results directly on the Scope?***

Remember: The Matlab Function Block has two ports, u and y. Which represents input and output respectively. In the above-given example, a sine-wave generator doesn't need an input.

Comment: You can configure the number of ports of a matlab function block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's just that you haven't chosen a very good example, but there are several things to be aware of when translating the code you've given into Simulink.

1. The easiest way to get the simulation time into a MATLAB Function block is by feeding a Clock block into an input port (which as @Daniel indicates, are optional, but in this case I suggest would be used for `t`).  So I think you do want an inport in this example.
2. Your use of `plot` in your example only plots the first 100 points, where as a Simulink Scope rolls through the data being displayed.  There's no concept of only displaying the first X points in a Scope when the simulation runs for longer than that.
3. You need to remember that Simulink generates data one simulation time step at a time, so you can't generate them all (as per your MATLAB code) and then plot them all.  (Well... you can if you want to use frame based signals, but I assume that's not what you're asking here.)

So, to implement the equivalent of what you have would involve doing the following.

- write a MATLAB Function block containing the following code (although you might want to make `A` and `f` input parameters rather than hard coding them)

  `function y = myCustomSineWave(t)
  A = 1;
  f =10000;
  y = A*sin(2*pi*f*t);`
- Feed a `Clock` block into the above block, and have a `Scope` block on its output